# DeepZoom + FileSystemWatcher class

Tags: filesystemwatcher

1. I am storing deepzoom tiles to a temporary folder using create function of collection creator class.
2. I am setting FilesystemWatcher class on the temporary folder where DeepZoom tiles get created.

When I Run the project in Debug Mode, and debug ucode using F10, i dont get any notification that the files are changes, but when i dont debug and press F5, i got notification events that "files in temporary folder is getting changed".

Is there any specific events where i am sure that deepzoom tile stuff is completed so that after that only i can set FileSystemWatcher class stuff.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but [the FileSystemWatcher class isn't entirely reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313942/filesystemwatcher-only-the-change-event-once-firing-once/1314104#1314104).