# Watch for files in a folder in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io, ftp

I need to watch a folder in our network and if any files get dropped in any time of the day I need to ftp to a different folder.

Is this a feasible approach? Are there some links that will take me in right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Use [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to watch the folder: Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when a directory, or file in a directory, changes.

Use [System.Net.FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) to send the file through FTP.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet might be the [filewatcher component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). It seems to work reasonable well over a network.

Answer (score 1):

To watch the file system, the (aptly named) [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) is a useful option.  There are many reports of unreliability however, so polling periodically is important.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-changes) for a small "Polling vs FileSystemWatcher" debate.

As far as the FTP upload goes, as Alfred says, [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

FileSystemWatcher as mentioned by the others will work fine in most cases, but not on Novell network drives.