# Is .NET's FileInfo.Length property lazy?

Tags: .net, file-io, lazy-evaluation

The following code generates a FileNotFoundException (using .NET 2.0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace LazyFileInfoTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            File.WriteAllText("Test.txt", "Hello World!");

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(".");

            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

            File.Delete("Test.txt");

            foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} Last Modified: {1}", fi.Name, fi.LastWriteTime));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} Last Modified: {1}", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime));
                //Exception when we reach test.txt
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} length is: {1}", fi.Name, fi.Length));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like the Length property is lazy. Is there any reason why? This seems like an inconsistency because it is not the case with other properties. (See [.NET FileInfo.LastWriteTime & FileInfo.LastAccessTime are wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448716/net-fileinfo-lastwritetime-fileinfo-lastaccesstime-are-wrong) for a counter example.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs for [FileInfo.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx):

> When first called, FileInfo calls
>   Refresh and caches information on the
>   file. On subsequent calls, you must
>   call Refresh to get the latest copy of
>   the information.

That seems to be correct - it looks like it's the other properties being eager which violates their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it is correct - the fileInfo object can exist even though there is no such file in the file system! It can still have a name, a directory et cetera. 
However, when you try to read its length, it needs to be bound to actual item in file system and read the length of file.

UPDATE:
Also, from [MSDN FileInfo documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) for *Length* property:

> When first called, FileInfo calls
>   Refresh and caches information on the
>   file.

So, refresh needs the file to be in place,otherwise you get an exception.