# C#: Get the 5 newest (last modified) files from a directory

Tags: c#, linq, file, directory

Is there a way I can store the file location of the 5 last modified files from a directory using `Array`?

I am currently using the following codes below to get the last file:

```
DateTime lastHigh = new DateTime(1900,1,1);
string highDir;
foreach (string subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(path)){
    DirectoryInfo fi1 = new DirectoryInfo(subdir);
    DateTime created = fi1.LastWriteTime;

    if (created > lastHigh){
        highDir = subdir;
        lastHigh = created;
    }
}
```

I'll be using `Array` to send multiple files to an email address as attachment.

**UPDATE**

I am currently using the codes below to get the last modified files after 1 minute:

```
string myDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures),
                  "Test Folder");
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(myDirectory);
DateTime from_date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1);
DateTime to_date = DateTime.Now;
var files = directory.GetFiles().Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= from_date && file.LastWriteTime <= to_date);
```

I want to store to list of file names coming from `files`

Comment: Are you just needing ".ToArray()" on the end of the files definition? ie `var files = directory.GetFiles().Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= from_date && file.LastWriteTime <= to_date).ToArray();`

Comment: @Michael I keep getting the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.IO.FileInfo'"

Comment: You have to create a `FileInfo` object from a path. Use the appropriate constructor, `new FileInfo(path)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a general way to do this with LINQ:

```
 Directory.GetFiles(path)
             .Select(x => new FileInfo(x))
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTime)
             .Take(5)
             .ToArray()
```

I suspect this isn't quite what you want, since your code examples seem to be working at different tasks, but in the *general* case, this would do what the title of your question requests.

Comment: How can I get the Lastest modified Directory on the same way?

Comment: While this answer works, I think the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179970/c-sharp-find-most-recent-file-in-dir might be better.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a `string` array of the full filepaths of all the files in a directory.

Given you already have your `FileInfo` enumerable, you can do this:

```
var filenames = files.Select(f => f.FullName).ToArray();
```

If you wanted just the filenames, replace `FullName` with `Name`.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer Paul Phillips provided worked. It's worth to keep in mind that the
`FileInfo.LastWriteTime` & `FileInfo.LastAccessTime` do not always work. It depends on how the OS is configured or could be a caching issue.

[.NET FileInfo.LastWriteTime & FileInfo.LastAccessTime are wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448716/net-fileinfo-lastwritetime-fileinfo-lastaccesstime-are-wrong)

[File.GetLastWriteTime seems to be returning 'out of date' value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992223/file-getlastwritetime-seems-to-be-returning-out-of-date-value)