# FileSystemWatcher does not inform about events on Samba share

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher, samba

I use the FileSystemWatcher in my C# application and this application runs as a Windows Service on my server. The watchers path is a Samba share from another network.
The application works totally fine when the folder path of the watcher is a folder on the Server, but with the shared folder no events are raised - I need to be informed when a file is created in the folder, then I move it to another one, rename it, read it and so on. (I also tried the watcher.Changed event but nothing is happening there either)

I found a similar question here:
[FileSystemWatcher with Samba on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306302/filesystemwatcher-with-samba-on-linux)

Does anybody know if the FSW has still problems with Samba-shared folders?
I already tried to use a StreamReader and StreamWriter to test if I even have access to the shared folder - this works without any problems. I also thought about resetting the EnableRaisingEvents to true if the FSW "breaks" (like it is mentioned in the question above) but I am a bit confused how to even find out if it broke - because I don't get an error, it just does nothing at all.

This is a part of my watcher class, it runs as a BackgroundService:

```cs
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    Initialize();
    TestAccessability();
    RunFileWatcher();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private void TestAccessability()
{
    // Get the directories currently on the shared drive.
    DirectoryInfo[] sDirs = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\10.18.249.8\halit4ind$").GetDirectories();

    // Write each directory name to a file.
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(importPath + "\\SDriveDirs.txt"))
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in sDirs)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(dir.Name);
        }
    }

    // Read and show each line from the file.
    string line = "";
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(importPath + "\\SDriveDirs.txt"))
    {
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}

private void RunFileWatcher()
{
    logger.LogInformation($"RunFileWatcher watching path {importPath}");
    watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
    {
        Path = @importPath,
        Filter = "*.csv"
    };

    watcher.Created += OnCreated;
    watcher.Changed += OnCreated;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    logger.LogInformation($"File {e.FullPath} created/changed - Type: {e.ChangeType}");
    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
    {
        var newFilename = TryMoveFileToWork(e.Name);
        MoveFileToArchiv(newFilename);
    }
}
```

This is the output I get in the console (I tried creating a file in \10.18.249.8\halit4ind$\Outbox but nothing happens):

```
pers
Inbox
Outbox
Work
Archiv
[07:19:57 INF] RunFileWatcher watching path \\10.18.249.8\halit4ind$\Outbox
[07:19:57 DBG] Failed to locate the development https certificate at 'null'.
[07:19:57 DBG] Hosting started
[07:19:57 DBG] Loaded hosting startup assembly InfoniqaServiceHali
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: D:\Services\InfoniqaServiceHali
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7040
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

This is the output I get if I use another path:

```
pers
Inbox
Outbox
Work
Archiv
[08:49:35 INF] RunFileWatcher watching path D:\temp\Outbox
[08:49:35 DBG] Failed to locate the development https certificate at 'null'.
[08:49:35 DBG] Hosting started
[08:49:35 DBG] Loaded hosting startup assembly InfoniqaServiceHali
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: D:\Services\InfoniqaServiceHali
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7040
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[08:49:44 INF] File D:\temp\Outbox\Personal.csv created/changed - Type: Created
[08:49:44 INF] TryMoveFileToWork Personal.csv
```

Comment: Is the application running under a User account, or is it running under a System or Service account? Did you check if that account has access to the share?

Comment: At the moment your question is identical to those already asked. If you want to narrow it, e.g. by providing a [mcve] that demonstrates your understanding of one of the proposed solutions and a failure to get it to work, that would be different. As far as detecting with FSW "breaks", that would depend on the specific scenario; in your case, probably polling is the only way, since according to you FSW never works in the first place.

Comment: @PeterB Yes, as far as I know I do have access to the folder, since reading and writing with the StreamReader & -Writer works.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I will try polling with a timer I think, since nothing I tried seems to work - thank you!