# C#: How to check if a open file has been updated

Tags: c#, io, filesystemwatcher

You know the feature for example, you opened `C:\test.txt` if you also have the same file in another editor, and you edit it there, when you return, the app will prompt that the file has changed, whether you want to update it. How do I check if the file has been updated?

**UPDATE**

Asked a sister question "[Using FileSystemWatcher to watch for changes to files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967658/c-using-filesystemwatcher-to-watch-for-changes-to-files)"

Comment: check out [filewatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Comment: Possibly related question which answers more than you're asking for, but will probably help with what you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-changes

Comment: @benjol: your linked question exactly mirrors my experience.

Comment: Don't use filewatcher, because you'll enter a realm of pain that you probably don't want to.  Poll the file for changes - look at date first, then size, then, the content.

Comment: @Daniel Mošmondor, will that be very slow?

Comment: @Daniel Mošmondor, I guess it shouldn't be a problem for me :) I am creating something like a text editor. but just curious

Comment: Also, I just discovered that `FileSystemWatcher` is not working for me ... see [sister question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967658/c-using-filesystemwatcher-to-watch-for-changes-to-files) for updates

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to get notifications from the file system.

Answer (score 5):

You can either use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx), or you can poll for changes at opportune moments.

Note that the `FileSystemWatcher` may miss changes if under heavy load and is `IDisposable`.   Failure to dispose it properly can cause stability issues (which I've had happen, personally).   If you opt for polling, note that `FileInfo` caches some metadata so you'll need to call the `FileInfo.Refresh` method if you reuse `FileInfo` objects.  Alternatively, use the `File` API.

For only a few files, polling is easier and safer to get right since it avoids the OS callback issues of FileSystemWatcher and never misses any events.  For large number of files, the `FileSystemWatcher` is a must to achieve reasonable performance.

Comment: No, you don't have to recreate the FileInfo, just call .Refresh() to force it to re-read

Answer (score 4):

Either use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) (preferred) or compare the last modified date periodically.

Comment: Asked a sister question [Using `FileSystemWatcher` to watch for changes to files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967658/c-using-filesystemwatcher-to-watch-for-changes-to-files)