# How reliable is the FileSystemWatcher in .netFramwork 4?

Tags: .net, filesystemwatcher

Has anyone used the FileSystemWatcher in framework 4 and have you encountered any problems?

i am using it in a windows service and i cant afford for it to fail.

I have heard from a friend that it is not very reliable but I have been testing for a few hours now and i havent had any problems but i am still doubting using it.....

i would appreciate any advice on this matter, i dont want to deliver the app to the the client and then realise that this thing is going to crash....

Thanks

---

Thanks for the advice guys

i think for my purposes it should be ok. it will be checking a folder on the local drive of the server and all its checking for is if a file have been modified so i think it should be fine

Comment: A lot of people have unreasonable expectations of the FileSystemWatcher - such as believing "Created" means the file exists, has all of the data it was intended to contain, and no other program is currently accessing it.

Comment: But there's also been cases in previous versions where FSW simply wouldn't pick up on obvious changes that it should have. I tried it once with the .net 2 version and found it useless for something as simple as watching for files being created (I wasn't even trying to access said files).

Comment: The `FileSystemWatcher` is not what I'd call "relaible". If reliability is critical its best to use it as a convenience and also use polling to ensure that no files are missed.  See [FileSystemWatcher vs polling to watch for file changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`FileSystemWatcher` relies on underlying file system support, so any reliability issues with the file system will be visible as reliability issues with `FileSystemWatcher`. For example, if you are watching a network directory, then the network server's reliability will affect `FileSystemWatcher`'s reliability. For example, the server may crash and be restarted. You will not be notified of changes that take place while network connectivity is lost. Or the server may [simply have a bug](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1293608&page=9) that prevents `FileSystemWatcher` from working reliably.

Another point is that `FileSystemWatcher` only watches for changes to metadata. [Not all file changes result in changes to metadata](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110812-00/?p=9913).

Comment: https://petermeinl.wordpress.com/2015/05/18/tamed-filesystemwatcher/

*This post shares robust wrappers around the standard FileSystemWatcher (FSW)  fixing problems commonly encountered when using it to monitor the file system in real-world applications.*