# File Delete does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written a function that deletes a file from it's location. The code can be seen as below:

```
if (File.Exists(strPath + "/FLV/" + flvvideoname))
{
    File.Delete(strPath + "/FLV/" + flvvideoname);
}
```

'strPath' is the path to the directory. When the code get's executed, the file doesn't always get deleted. Running the same code over and over will delete the file. When I troubleshoot this issue, the break point doesn't go past the file delete line and I don't see any errors either. If the break point makes it past the file delete line, that means the file has been deleted properly.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any other processes accessing that file?

Comment: Make sure that the user which runs IIS process has rights to modify this directory.

Comment: `Delete does not delete a file that is open for normal I/O or a file that is memory mapped.`

Comment: If the condition is met than the `File.Delete` will be executed, if no exception is thrown that means the file has been deleted.

Comment: Use `System.IO.Path.Combine(strPath, "FLV", flvvideoname)`

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev  think this had to do with permissions to the folder. I'll check

Comment: @OrelEraki But the file does not get deleted and the break point doesn't go past the file delete line and breaks out

Comment: Is it fullpath or relative?

Comment: @BoasEnkler It's the full path.

Comment: Is strPath in relative path too?

Comment: what you mean with " the break point doesn't go past the file delete line"? the debugger never executes that line (the condition is not met) but gets to the end or the execution is stuck just before that line?

Comment: Have a look at the output i would assume that a exception is thrown but the debugger doesn't stop. For debugging you can put a try catch around it and see wether a exception is thrown perhaps its something like a permission or lock problem

Comment: @Paolo The break point disappears and the program continues to run

Comment: is the breakpoint greyed out or really not shown  ? if greyed out hower over it and look wether it says that you have not current sources

Comment: @BoasEnkler The break point just disappears and code after the delete line never get's executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handle from file creation can sometimes be not freed. Try calling

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

before deleting.

Also check out this SO question: [Delete a file being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262548/delete-a-file-being-used-by-another-process/21137207#21137207).

EDIT:

Alternatively to awoid calling GC.Collect() (for reasons pointed out by Boas Enker), you may want to wait for the file in a loop - [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50800/3922292).

Comment: Not a good idea. GC.Collect has a huge impact on the whole runtime. also it doesn't solve the problem and makes the system less predictable

Comment: @BoasEnkler I have tried this method and it worked. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba There are some dirty, like using Thread.Sleep(), but you do not wont to go this way.

Comment: The question is why is the file locked. is there more code accessign that file ? are you flushing and disposing other actors that access the file?

Comment: @BoasEnkler The answer to you qustion is, that while creating the file (File.Create), the file handle is sometimes not released (finalized) before the delete call. Check it out, with just Thread.Sleep(2000); it should work too, but is nondeterministic and dirty. GC class is just for this sort of stuff.

Comment: I disagree, I would more like to check in a loop wether the  action was successfull instead of calling gc.collect. In small prototype application it isn't important but when having a normal - big sizd application and you have gc.collect in such a  "detail" event which may be recurring a lot of time then you could just mess up the whole garbage collection.... see forexample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118633/whats-so-wrong-about-using-gc-collect Retrying the action (if nothing else possible) would only have a local effect and would not negativly influence the whole runtime

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I have used the loop and it works. @PiotrFalkowski

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that problem not in File deletion. May be when you are retrieving Filename from database, or setting some variable dynamically, you do this not in the first page load, but even at postbacks. So if you are retrieving filename dynamically, do the next step:

```
if (!IsPostBack){//function for retrieving data from database
```

`//your_variable = some_value;
}`