# Asynchronous message passing in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, messaging

I am looking for a simple .NET library that implements a concept of async message passing similar to Erlang OTP platform. So far, I have only found RetLang to be somewhat similar, but

1. It seems to be abandoned, and
2. It only supports message passing within one process.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with MSMQ .you can use for single or a group of messages you want to put in the queue and read from it later asynchronously. :)

Comment: This is dead tech. It's barely in maintenance mode at this point. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the easiest way to do this in .net (aside from F# ;) ) is the T[PL dataflow - lib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/devlabs/gg585582)

Answer (score 1):

Use MSMQ which is quite simple to implement. It is exactly what you need - asynchronous messaging system. WCF is also good but is more complex to manage (config files) and adds a bit of overhead. MSMQ is a standard (and free) Windows component but to use it you need to enable it. MSMQ can be used for local communication (same process or any 2 processes within the same Windows domain)

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9410871/78534) answer for more details and code examples.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft research developed and proved out (with EA/Bioware) a project called Orleans. It has been used in production and is being actively developed.

[Quick Summary](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/orleans-virtual-actors/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fprojects%2Forleans%2F)

[Intro on Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/microsoft-orleans-introduction)

https://github.com/dotnet/orleans

Answer (score 0):

You can use WCF to send and receive asynchronous messages. you can read more at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [spring messaging](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/messaging.html), this might be useful for you.