# Multiple FileSystemWatcher objects

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I need to watch several (maybe up to 50) different directories (some inc. subdirectories) for changes to files.

All these directories are on network shares. The network shares contain log files which are updated constantly.

Now I have heard that FileSystemWatcher is unreliable (missing events) and won't work with watching this many directories.

Now the unreliability is not an issue as I don't need to pick up every event because events would be raised at sub-second level if it did, I am more concerned with the scalability of how many you can actually use.

So my question is, should I build my own polling system watcher (every 5 seconds for instance) and iterate through all the files in the directories being watched or is this the wrong was to go about it?

How do I overcome my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use FileSystemWatcher and ocasually check for changes. You can lower the polling time according to importance or urgency.

More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes).