# Observable delay item waiting for some condition

Tags: system.reactive

I have an Observable of file created. I want delay the emission of item for file that are locked because still opened in write.

```
Created = Observable
                .FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(h => Watcher.Created += h, h => Watcher.Created -= h)
                .Select(x => x.EventArgs);

CreatedAndNotLockedObservable = ?
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Try adding `.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))` to your observable.

Comment: I wrote an answer myself here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56092132/3360759
@Enigmativity please take a look