# FileSystemWatcher OnChanged event

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to see what exactly changed when OnChanged is called?  I am trying to filter out file attribute changes.

Comment: In the event you weren't aware [FileSystemWatcher doesn't always behave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes).

Answer (score 2):

The method provides an argument of type [`FileSystemEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemeventargs.aspx), which supplies data on the type and path of the change.

You can use this to filter only the `WatcherChangeTypes.Changed` value, which is:

> The change of a file or folder. The types of changes include: changes
>   to size, attributes, security settings, last write, and last access
>   time.

See @Oliver's answer for the supplemental info to this answer, I was just about to add that :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NotifyFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter.aspx) property to specify what kind of change you want to observe. As Rotem already stated the `FileSystemEventArgs` class also provides some information of a change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can filter out anything as granular as which attributes were changed.  You can use the `NotifyFilters` property to specify that you only want to raise events when file attributes were changed.  The event is raised when each change happens so you can in response to the event simply create a `FileInfo` class with the provided path of the file and inspect the new attributes.