# How to desirialize objects from an XML file and keep them updated from the file?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

My XML file will contain some geometric objects. Like Square or Ellipse.

My question is, if I modify the XML file how can I update those integrated objects without do it myself?

It's kinda like a template.

If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Did not get your question. If you update XML by serializing object then you already have updated object. Don't you?

Comment: How exactly are you planning on modifying the XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call specific code when a file is modified, you can use [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Simply set its Path property to your file directory's path, its Filter property to your file's name, and implement its Changed event, in which you'll reload your shapes.

Edit: do note that [there might be some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes) (mainly with remote files, local ones appear to be watched fine) with this class; you may have to replace or complete it with a manual polling of the desired file to watch.