# Change ToolStripButtomItem Attributes Using EventHandler

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, event-handling, toolstripbutton

this is my first question on stackoverflow, therefore errors in asking-style aren't on purpose.

I'm both, new to C# as to the concept of event-handling, so
I would like to know, if there is any possibility to have the value of an ToolStripButtonItem-attribute changed by an EventHandler.

The context is the following:

The code starts by initializing the UI which contains some Windows.Forms- Elements. 
The `ToolStripButtomItem` that is of interest for me, has it's `Enabled-attribute` set to false as default-value. The functionality of this button is to switch into a comparision-view as soon as a certain reference file exists.
This allready can be the case when the programm-start, otherwise the reference file might be created during runtime.
Of course, you could perform

```
Button.Enabled=System.IO.File.Exists(Reference-File)
```

with the initilization and than do something like

```
CreateFile(ReferenceFile){
    ...
    Button.Enabled = true;
}
```

but this seems rather crude to me.

Instead I would like to something like:

```
Button.Enabled = new System.EventHandler(this.EnableButton);
```

with

```
private void EnableButton(Object sender, EventArgs e){
  if(System.IO.FileExists(ReferenceFile)
  Button.Enabled = true; 
}
```

What I intend is, to have the button get enabled as soon as the reference-file existst. There are multiple ways to create the reference-file, and there are goint to be even more in the future. To avoid setting the enable-value in each of those `createReferenceFile()`-Methods, the concept of EventHandling seems quite like the deal to me.

The program I'm trying to run is quite comprehensive, so "polling" is no option at this place.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the FileSystemWatcher and set the enabled property every time it goes of.

```
    private void StartListening(string path)
    {
        var watch = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watch.Path = path;
        watch.Filter = "*.*";
        watch.Created += UpdateState;
        watch.Deleted += UpdateState;
    }

    void UpdateState(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        MyButton.Enabled = File.Exists(@"C:\Folder\File.txt");
    }
```

PS: this is just some very basic example code, you will need to make sure that you have a reference to `MyButton` and have the correct path there as well ...

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Hence the programm is quite comprehensive and performs bilateral changes in the file-code and the associated visualization as well, it would be interessting to know, how ressource-intensive your suggestion is? It looks a little bit like default "polling", which I would like to avoid at all.

Comment: Not at all, as far as I know it is pure event driver. So no polling. The only problem you may run into is if there would be to many changes in a short  time, because then you could miss one. (Changes are buffered and handled one by one with a max of ~128 items in the buffer I think.) I do not know the details though, this is just something I remember ...
PS, you should probably use `MyButton.InvokeRequired()` and `MyButton.Invoke(new Action(() => UpdateState(sender, e)));` because I think the events may originate from another thread.

Comment: Seems to me, like `FileSystemWatcher` is pretty unstable and likely to fail, which would not be acceptable at this point.

Comment: And what makes you think that?

Comment: The FileSystemWatcher was nothing I knew, until you proposed it as an probably fitting concept. So I did a little research and came up with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes

Comment: Yep there are some issues. If you think it is realistic that lots of changes could happen in a short time you will need to combine it with a polling mechanism to be sure. Still it is the only way I know of that can give you real time & no polling results. (PS: about the leaking -> don't forget to unsubscribe from the events if you stop using it ! ) (And that is a general warning if you are working with events and not familiar with them)