# Edit control's property every X second

Tags: c#

I am currently developping an application where I need to check if the user has replaced a file (by MD5) and I thought of a Timer.

A Timer that checks every 1-2 seconds If the MD5 of the file is not what I expected, If not, I need to disable a MenuStripItem.

My question is, is it bad to edit a control's property every 1-2 seconds?

Comment: I think what you need is a [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying a control's property every 1-2 seconds does not seem like a bad idea, but checking a file's hash so often seems like a bad idea. You should at least compare the file dates and size before comparing the hash.
A better approach would be to check it only when the menu item is used.
`FileSystemWatcher` is the usual way to keep track of changes in a folder, but it is not fully reliable [FileSystemWatcher vs polling to watch for file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes)