# How to detect a file being removed from folder

Tags: c#

I am trying to detect when a file is being removed from a folder in my drive.  Upon detection, I want to write code that does something.  Is there an event handler for this kind of 'event' in C#?  Looked around but couldn't find any.  Is it even possible?

Comment: Filesystemwatcher will do the job. Look here for a similar topic [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes)

Answer (score 1):

You can use FileSystemWatcher to monitor a directory, and subscribe to it's `Deleted` event. See the code below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = "C:/some/directory/to/watch";
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                           NotifyFilters.LastWrite  | 
                           NotifyFilters.FileName   | 
                           NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
    watcher.Filter = "*.*";
    watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleted);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private static void OnDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```